# Custom replies for facebook messenger on apple watch

Tags: ios, facebook, apple-watch, facebook-messenger

I am running the version 201.0 of facebook messenger on Iphone 7 and i'm trying to set apple watch custom replies.

I would like to delete or replace default **yes** or **no** replies messages and use the ones i configured in iphone app messages.

In facebook messenger app settings there is no apple watch link so that i can set replies settings.

Please how to set those custom replies for apple watch ?